# Javascript Setting attribute onchange event to select and displaying to console stops after first selection

Tags: javascript

I am trying to log the value of the option selected by adding an `onchange` event. The problem is it only logs once and stops. What am I missing here?

```js
var selection = document.getElementById("test-dropdown");
selection.setAttribute("onchange", function() {
  console.log((selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text));
}());
```

```html
<select id="test-dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few minor errors to fix in your code to get this working as required.

First remove the `()` after the definition of your handler function. By adding the `()`, this is causing the handler function to be executed once only, and immediatly, when the script first runs.

By removing the `()`, this causes the function to be passed as an argument to `addEventHandler()` ( as in my code below ), and will cause it to only be called when the `change` event is fired.

Second, consider using `addEventListener()` rather than `setAttribute()` to bind the `change` event to your `<select/>` element. With this approach, you'd also pass the event name of `change` (rather than setting the `onchange` attribute) as follows:

```html
<select id="test-dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<script>
  var selection = document.getElementById("test-dropdown");

  // Using addEventListener() to bind custom change event handler
  selection.addEventListener("change", function() {

    console.log((selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text));

  }); // <--- removed the () 
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to explain those *"minor errors"* and the changes you have made to make this work?

Comment: @NewToJS pressed post before finished writing answer :)

Comment: Fair enough. Some people post a solution without bothering to explain it which I find pointless if people wish to learn from answers/solutions but at least you have explained everything in your update. I will **+1** now that it is helpful to the OP and others who stumble on this.

Comment: @JaredFoster glad I could help - please consider accepting the answer if it has been helpful :)

Comment: @NewToJS yeah I see that a lot also, so make an effort to avoid doing that - have just added a bit more detail to hopefully improve it further :)

Comment: @DacreDenny I'm sure this will be very helpful :) I have **+1** for solution and detail given.

Comment: @DacreDenny Very welcome. I am here to help any way I can and since you posted a good solution I thought it would be better to give my feedback rather than  writing something similar causing a duplicate. Feedback is always good :) I know I appreciate it too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are missing binding. The way currently you are doing it is on render only.

You need to create a function first

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("test-dropdown").value;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<select id="test-dropdown" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```